# Is saving children possible without freeing the spirit in "the whispering hillock"?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In The Witcher 3, in "The Whispering Hillock" quest, is there any way to kill the spirit in the tree and then find the crones and save the children?

Or kill the crones before this mission so the children would not be taken by them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible to all of your questions.

Killing the tree spirit will immediately make the children go missing from the game world. You will not find them and not be able to save them.

You are never given an opportunity to kill the Crones at any time during this quest line, so killing them is not possible either.